# How do I create a Firebird database file programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, firebird, firebird-embedded

How do I create a Firebird database file programmatically?

I've written code using SQLite (C# .NET, System.Data.SQLite)
... decided to try Firebird.

To install Firebird: Windows 7 -> Visual Studio 2013 -> File -> New -> Project, etc. ---------- then Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages -> search "firebird" -> Firebird ADO.NET Data provider ->
Install (button).

Resulted in a) References -> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, and b)
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.5.8.0 subdir ... with Firebird .dll's.

To create a Firebird database file, I've tried (extracted from another StackOverflow post):

```
int pageSize = 4096;
bool forcedWrites = true;
bool overwrite = false;
var connectionString = new FbConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Database = stPathFilename,
    ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded,
    UserID = "SYSDBA",
    Password = "masterkey",
    ClientLibrary = "fbclient.dll"
}.ToString();
FbConnection.CreateDatabase(connectionString, pageSize, forcedWrites, overwrite);
```

I had presumed this is standard, except for the stPathFilename. However, this code throughs an exception ... complains about fbclient.dll.

Then I tried

```
    ClientLibrary = "FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll"
```

... which is located in my Debug subdir.

This throws an exception ... "Unable to find an entry point named 'isc_create_database' in DLL 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll".

How do I create a Firebird database file programmatically?

Comment: As also indicated on the Firebird-net-provider mailinglist, having the Firebird ADO.net provider is not sufficient, you need to include Firebird Embedded yourself, otherwise you only have a client to connect to a (normal) Firebird server. I'll try to post  more complete answer this weekend, but I'm a bit short on time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a crucial point, the Firebird ADO.net provider is not like `System.Data.SQLite`: it is **not** a Firebird database engine, it is only a client to connect to a Firebird server, by default through a pure C# implementation of the Firebird TCP/IP wire protocol, alternatively using the native client or to an embedded 'server' (a native client API that talks directly to an in-process database engine).

The first option has no dependencies, but the second and third option have native dependencies that you need to provide yourself (it is not part of FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient).

For native you need `fbclient.dll`, for Firebird Embedded you need Firebird Embedded: for Firebird 2.5 and earlier: `fbembed.dll` and dependencies, for Firebird 3 `fbclient.dll` + `plugins\engine12.dll` and dependencies.

There is little wrong with your code itself, but to get it running you need to do the following to get Firebird Embedded:

1. Download the latest Firebird 3 zip kit (use 32 bit for a 32-bit or AnyCPU application, 64 bit for a 64-bit application).

   At the time of writing the latest version is Firebird 3.0.1. You can get it from the [Firebird 3 download page](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-3-0/), look for *"Zip kit for manual/custom installs"* under Win32 or Win64.
2. Unzip it in a folder (for example `D:\Temp\fb3embedded`)
3. You can keep all the files, but you can delete most of them as they are not necessary for Firebird Embedded (the zipkit is also a full Firebird server). You should retain the following:

   - `intl` folder and all contents (necessary for character set and collation support)
   - `plugins\engine12.dll` (the database engine itself, other files in `plugins` may be deleted, but this may restrict some features)
   - `fbclient.dll` (main entrypoint for the embedded engine)
   - `firebird.msg` (contains error messages)
   - `icu*` (necessary for character set and collation support)
   - You may need to retain the `msvcp100.dll` and `msvcr100.dll` if not already installed (but it usually is on most recent Windows systems)

Technically you can also remove `intl`, but that will limit character set support.

In your code, instead of `ClientLibrary = "fbclient.dll"` specify `ClientLibrary = @"D:\Temp\fb3embedded\fbclient.dll"`, and it will work. For a deployed application, you can also put Firebird Embedded inside your application folder and use a relative path.

For Firebird 2.5 and earlier, the instructions are similar, but instead you download the Embedded zip kit of that version, unzip it in a folder, and point `ClientLibrary` to the `fbembed.dll` (and not `fbclient.dll`) in that folder.

Just be aware that `FbConnection.CreateDatabase` will throw an exception if the database already exists and you have specified `overwrite` as `false`.